# List vs. DataTable vs. DataSet

Tags: c#, list, datatable, dataset

I am writing a program that performs different string operations on every letter of the alphabet. The different possibilities are stored in lists, where one operation is randomly selected.  Basically I could set up the program with 26 different lists, but that means that I have to have my functions copied 26 times to refer to the different lists, and that is rather tedious.

I have hesitations about writing my program with a DataTable because I need each separate column to be independent.  The operations in the "A" column are completely distinct from the operations in column "B".  If I delete an entry in A, I would like the entries below it to move up, instead of having a null value in the table. I would like to be able to refer to the lists or datatables like table["A"][1].toSting(), etc.

**TLDR; With standard programming convention, is it better to add lists to a dataTable, or is it better to add DataTables to a DataSet?  Which is standard?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about `Dictionary<char, List<operation>>` ?

Comment: If I set it up like that and later decided that I wanted to add additionally data to each character, would that be easy?

Comment: If you want to support multiple characters as key, use a `Dictionary<string, List<operation>>` instead - is that what you mean? If you meant adding operations to a character, then you can just `MyDictionary['a'].Add(additionalOperation);`

Comment: Well, I've considered adding a frequency value to each character, which would then require a datatable I think, with the two columns of data.  With this, I can use MyDictionary['a'].RemoveAt, or .Add() .Clear(), etc.  It's just the dictionary[key].ListFunction, right?

Comment: Currently, from the question I understand there is a certain `Condition` (character) and if a `Condition` is met, a random `Operation` assigned to that `Condition` is performed. If frequency is to be part of the condition, you could create a `Condition` struct to hold character and frequency, and use that as the key of the `Dictionary<Condition, List<Operation>>`. Perhaps more information about what you're trying to achieve would point into a different direction?

Comment: Well, I'm taking a character, like a, and then converting it to another character from the database.  It isn't really encryption, it is just switching text randomly from a list of options.  I would allow the user to determine frequency of the options as well.  Would that force me to use a DataTable or create a custom type to store the character option and the frequency value?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR; With standard programming convention, is it better to add lists to a dataTable, or is it better to add DataTables to a DataSet? Which is standard?**

Just going off your TLDR; question, adding DataTables to a DataSet is the standard. Period.